# NSURLSession data always zero bytes

Tags: ios, swift

I swear it was working the other day and now I get data as zero bytes in the response back. The result variable is empty. Am I being blocked by Flickr API?

Here is my code:

```
func setup() {

    let flickrURL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=texas&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?"

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    (session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string :flickrURL)!, completionHandler: { (data :NSData!, response, error) -> Void in

        let result = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        // convert result into JSON dictionary 
      //  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        println("\(result!)")



    })).resume()

}
```

Here is what is stored in the error parameter:

```
Printing description of error.Some:
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)" UserInfo=0x7fde2da8f390 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=texas&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=texas&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fde2da63430 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1005.)"}
```

Comment: You have an error parameter in the completion block. Use it!

Comment: I pasted the error parameter description.

Comment: Try to restart your simulator.

Comment: @LeoNatan Can you believe it! That worked :) If you can post as an answer I will accept it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the simulator should solve this issue.